# Can't insert in database with Codeigniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I'm trying to add everything from a table (transactions) then try to insert all the totals to another table(reports_daily), but nothing is inserted.

**transaction.php**

```
 public function index()
 {
      $this->load->model('transactions_model');  
      $transresult = $this->transactions_model->get_transactions_list();           
      $data['translist'] = $transresult;
      $this->load->view('transactions_view',$data);
 }
 function create() {

     $transresult = $this->transactions_model->get_transactions_list();           
      $data['translist'] = $transresult;
        $sum=0;
        $items=0;
        $orders=0;
        $date=$translist[0]->date_d;
        for ($i=0; $i<count($translist); ++$i){
          $sum += $translist[$i]->total_amount;
          $items += $translist[$i]->no_items;
          $orders++;
        }
      $data = array(
        'date_d' => $date,
        'total_items' => $items,
        'total_orders' => $orders,
        'total_sales' => $sum
      );
      //$this->db->set($data);
      //$this->db->insert('reports_daily', $data);
      $this->transactions_model->insert_reports($data);
      $this->index();


  }
```

**transactions_model.php**

```
 function get_transactions_list()
 {
      $sql = 'select * from transactions order by date_d desc';
      $query = $this->db->query($sql);
      $result = $query->result();
      return $result;
 }
 function insert_reports($data) 
 {
      $this->db->insert('reports_daily', $data);
      return;
 }
```

Help :(

Comment: use `$this->db->last_query()` to echo your query and look into error

Comment: Did you check the error logs ?

Comment: there were no errors :(

Comment: `$translist` is not defined as used in the create() method. There seem to be a confusion between the `$translist`array and the `$transresult` object.

Comment: There are more funny things in this code. What is the purpose of the `$date` variable for instance?

Comment: Are you auto loading your transactions_model class?

Answer (score 0):

`$translist` is not exist on controller. So use `$transresult[0]` instead of `$translist[0]`;

```
function create() {

 $transresult = $this->transactions_model->get_transactions_list();           

    $sum=0;
    $items=0;
    $orders=0;
    $date = $transresult[0]->date_d;
    for ($i=0; $i<count($translist); ++$i){
      $sum += $translist[$i]->total_amount;
      $items += $translist[$i]->no_items;
      $orders++;
    }
  $data = array(
    'date_d' => $date,
    'total_items' => $items,
    'total_orders' => $orders,
    'total_sales' => $sum
  );
  //$this->db->set($data);
  //$this->db->insert('reports_daily', $data);
  $this->transactions_model->insert_reports($data);
  $this->index();
```

}